# iPhone SDK - How to save and resume timer Label when app is closed and reopened

Tags: objective-c, save, nstimer

I have a countdown timer that when you start it, it creates a notification and sets it to fire for the time that the countdown timer is set for. I also start a 1 second timer to update the label when it goes down. Once I receive the local notification, if the app is open I hit the didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification function and if I'm not in the app the local notification pops up. Everything works fine if I stay in the app or just close it and that is it. The problems occur when I try to multitask with multiple apps.

I have noticed the following and I am not sure how to fix it:

1. If I start the timer, then close the app by hitting the home button once then open another app and do some stuff and then open my app back up, the timer label does not remember the time it left off at. I tried saving the end NSDate in the viewdiddisappear method but I'm not sure when to resume it as if I switch tabs while the app is still open, it will get saved and I won't know how to update.
2. If you start the time and then double tap home and force close the app, no code is called so I was unable to save the time. How would I be able to resume then?

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

in your .h file take this objects.

```
NSTimer *gameTimer;
NSDate *pauseStart, *previousFireDate;
```

then, in your .m file when you pause and save timer value than use this code

```
pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] ;
previousFireDate = [gameTimer fireDate] ;
[gameTimer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

then, when you want to resume your timer then use this code

```
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
[gameTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
```

then, if you want to store transitions for background and foreground then use `NSUserDefaults` to store timer count and use it to pause and resume. You can use `appdelegate` action to handle this events in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` for this.

if you are in same view when coming in foreground, then you can get notification of it by this code in your `viewdidload` method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someAction) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

and you can handle timer in your `someAction` method.